# Microphone signal from USB soundcard is silent in any application that uses Pulseaudio, including the Settings

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, microphone, external-soundcard

**I can record audio from it in Audacity just fine** (it apparently uses ALSA to interact with sound card).

Not so much with any application that uses Pulseaudio, they see the device but there's always no signal. Input indicator in Settings also always looks like it's completely silent.

What could go wrong and how to fix it?

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems it gets solved by "clean reinstall" of pulseaudio with `sudo apt purge pulseaudio && sudo apt install pulseaudio` but it had to remove `ubuntu-desktop` package which I'm not sure if it's OK...

Comment: You seem not to be using "Ubuntu-Desktop" (or you would be asking another question) - but you could try to reinstall the meta package with `sudo apt install ubuntu-desktop` - assuming that you think you need it!

Comment: @CharlesGreen I don't know if I need it. I tried this command and it started to install terabytes of some random stuff so I pressed Ctrl+C ASAP and decided to make a decision later. But maybe there's a chance it hides something important in there too.

Comment: The desktop meta packages are interesting in an abstract sort of way - they set how the screen appears, and install a raft of routines and programs that the developers think go well with the desktop and its appearance.  ***All*** of these packages and routines can be installed seperately, if desired.

Comment: alright, it seems everything was fine "without" "ubuntu-desktop" since that day... fwiw

Comment: i have v8 sound card and this also my case, i tried the solution above and did not work